# Barcode Scanner using RN Camera is very slow in android expected as smooth as that of ios

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-camera

Scanning on Android is not working as intended, or it takes time to scan

3 different libraries i Have used:
zxy
firebase-ml-vision
Google vision

Config is::
**react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
"react-native-camera": "3.37.0"**

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
*  Boosts up barcode read performance on Android
*/
import { RNCamera, RNCameraProps } from 'react-native-camera';


const RNCameraProps: RNCameraProps = {};

if (Platform.OS === OS.IOS) {
  RNCameraProps.onBarCodeRead = ({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
} else {
  RNCameraProps.onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected = ({ barcodes }) => {
    const response = barcodes[0];
    console.log(response);
  };
}

return(
  <RNCamera
    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
    style={styles.camera}
    {...RNCameraProps}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution from 2022:

1. Use the Vision Camera component https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/ because it is very close to native performance.
2. For QR/Barcode detection use this frame processor for Vision Camera https://github.com/rodgomesc/vision-camera-code-scanner which uses ML Kit under the hood.